# Rearranging list items based on a score to fit a function curve

Tags: python, list, sorting, curve

Given that I have:

- a list of words
- points/scores that indicates "simplicity" for each word
- the difficulty levels of each word:

E.g.

```
>>> words = ['apple', 'pear', 'car', 'man', 'average', 'older', 'values', 'coefficient', 'exponential']
>>> points = ['9999', '9231', '8231', '5123', '4712', '3242', '500', '10', '5']
>>> bins = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Currently, the word list is ordered by the simplicity `points`.

**What if I want to model the simplicity as a "quadratic curve"?**, i.e. from highest to a low point and then back to high, i.e. produce a word list that looks like this with the corresponding points:

```
['apple', 'pear', 'average', 'coefficient', 'exponential', 'older', 'values', 'apple', 'pear']
```

I have tried this but it's painfully crazy:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(bins)[0]
4
>>> num_easy, num_mid, num_hard = Counter(bins)[0], Counter(bins)[1], Counter(bins)[2]
>>> num_easy
4
>>> easy_words = words[:num_easy]
>>> mid_words = words[num_easy:num_easy+num_mid]
>>> hard_words = words[-num_hard:]
>>> easy_words, mid_words, hard_words
(['apple', 'pear', 'car', 'man'], ['average', 'older', 'values'], ['coefficient', 'exponential'])
>>> easy_1 = easy_words[:int(num_easy/2)]
>>> easy_2 = easy_words[len(easy_1):]
>>> mid_1 = mid_words[:int(num_mid/2)]
>>> mid_2 = mid_words[len(mid_1):]
>>> new_words = easy_1 + mid_1 + hard_words + mid_2 + easy_1 
>>> new_words
['apple', 'pear', 'average', 'coefficient', 'exponential', 'older', 'values', 'apple', 'pear']
```

Imagine the no. of bins is >3 or maybe I want to "points" of the words to fit an sine-shape curve.

Note that this has not exactly an `nlp` question nor it has anything to do with 'zipf' distribution and creating something to match or reorder the ranking of the word.

Imagine there's a list of integers you have an object (in this case a word) map to each integer and you want to reorder the list of object to fit a quadratic curve.

Comment: Are the `points` irrelevant or is the `bin` value derived of the points?

Comment: The bins are derived from the points.

Comment: you mention "the word list is ordered by the simplicity `points`" but `points` doesn't look ordered in your example as it has subsequence `'5123', '3242', '4712'`. Is there anything wrong in my understanding?

Comment: @Rohanil, typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do sth along these lines. Sort the words by their points, take every second out, reverse that half and concat the two:

```
>>> s = sorted(zip(map(int, points), words))
>>> new_words = [word for p, word in list(reversed(s[::2])) + s[1::2]]
# If you have lots of words you'll be better off using some 
# itertools like islice and chain, but the principle becomes evident
>>> new_words
['apple', 'car', 'older', 'values', 'exponential', 'coefficient', 'average', 'man', 'pear']
```

Ordered as in:

```
[(9999, 'apple'), (8231, 'car'), (4712, 'older'), (500, 'values'), (5, 'exponential'), (10, 'coefficient'), (3242, 'average'), (5123, 'man'), (9231, 'pear')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort it into a list according to your custom criteria, check whether its length is even or odd, then zip it in chunks of two and reverse the last half:

```
>>> def peak(s):
...     return s[::2]+s[-1-(len(s)%2)::-2]
...
>>> peak('112233445566778')
'123456787654321'
>>> peak('1122334455667788')
'1234567887654321'
```

Note that uneven data may produce asymmetrical results:

```
>>> peak('11111123')
'11123111'
```